# How can I remove my emails from the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail

On an Android phone, Gmail app is showing emails from my Gmail account despite that I have never authorised that app to access the account.

This started when [EDIT:] I logged-in to Google Play Store [], and then got a new email notification from a Gmail app installed on the same device but never accessed by me. Accessing it shows it has emails of mine.

I tried removing the Google account from the device and disabling the Gmail app following the instruction on [Google Support - Sign out of Gmail](https://web.archive.org/web/20221018210321/https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1), but when reenabled it, it still shows my emails.

How can I remove my emails from the Gmail app?

Comment: All Google apps use the same Google account registered in Android settings. If you are logged in into a Google app all the other installed Google apps als have access to the account. The only way to avoid that is not install the corresponding app. So in your case you can only uninstall Gmail (or remove the Google account from your device).

Comment: Continuation from OP's question on WebApps.SE: [How does Android Chrome manage to leak a Google Account log-in to the Gmail app?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/167247/79784)

Comment: "The only way to avoid that is not install the corresponding app." I didn't install it. It was pre-installed. So I take it "The only way to avoid that is not have the corresponding app."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail syncs emails on the device for users' convenience (e.g. offline viewing). To clear synced emails from the device, try clearing the app data from its app info:

1. Navigate to Android Settings - Apps - See all N apps - Gmail
2. Select "Storage & cache"
3. Tap "Clear storage" and "Clear cache"

<sup>Based on Pixel 3a, Android 12. Menu might be different on other devices.</sup>