# How does Android Chrome manage to leak a Gmail.com log-in to the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail, chrome-for-android, password

Using Android 12 and Chrome, when I logged in to gmail.com, I got a new email notification from a Gmail app installed on the same device but never accessed by me.

How did supposedly secure Chrome leak my login to this Gmail app?

(And I can't remove the emails captured by the Gmail app from it. Despite removing the Google account from the device and disabling the Gmail app, when enabled it still shows my emails.)

UPDATE: This report is incomplete, omitting to mention that immediately prior, I'd logged-in to the Google Play Store app (to get Chrome). See my own answer below.

Comment: Are you logged into Google Play Store app or any other Google app on that device?

Comment: OP's follow-up question: [How can I remove my emails from the Gmail app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248856/44325)

Answer (score -1):

Asker here. Answer: It did not.

Further testing showed the culprit was not Chrome but Google Play Store (initially omitted from the report), and no log-ins to Gmail on Chrome are showing this leak.